# Wordpress - Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by - only when logged in

Tags: wordpress

On my site, when I navigate the site while logged out, everything is fine. But when I log in then go to any page other than the homepage, I get a white screen and that headers already sent error message.

The front page works while I'm logged in, and so does wp-admin. But none of the other pages work while logged in.

What could cause this particular problem?

Heres what the error shows:
[image]

Comment: There is a script that is trying to set a header (like a cookie, a redirect...) after some output has been printed. But if you provide no details we can't help you...

Comment: Is there a way to pinpoint where its happening? A new problem has appeared, I can't login to the site at all anymore, I enter the login details and it just redirects back to the login page.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out where this script is thats causing problems?

Comment: give us more details... what does the error say? filename and line number

Comment: I added the details there.

Answer (score 0):

That notice error output is the problem.

You should fix that error (some plugin or theme is calling a deprecated function `get_currentuserinfo`, just rename `get_currentuserinfo()` to `wp_get_current_user()`), or otherwise edit php.ini to not to print notice errors